# How do I configure the LIS3DH as a pedometer that generates interrupts when walking?

Tags: interrupts, accelerometer

I found a lot of algorithms for pedometers that assume a fast CPU with a decent ALU and high sampling rates, which I don't have. (Z80) However, the LIS3DH has various options for generating interrupts when some condition occurs.

How can I configure it such that it generates interrupts when I'm walking?
High accuracy is not needed, I just need to know if the user is moving or not.

I looked through the datasheet, but there are more options than I can wrap my head around. Click detection looked promising, but gave useless, semi-random results, maybe because it only detects fast clicks and not walking speeds. There are also options for free-fall interrupt, inertial interrupt, orientation detection, high-pass filter, FIFO, and more.

I'll sleep on it and toil along tomorrow, but any wise words are hugely appreciated.

[Datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/LIS3DH.pdf)
[Application note](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/LIS3DHappnote.pdf)

Comment: It is unclear why you need the LIS3DH to generate interrupts. A Z80 isn't super fast, but still quite a lot of instructions/second. I would normally expect to monitor the sensor at a regular rate, say 1kHz. By sampling at a regular rate it should be easier to estimate speed and direction than from interrupts.

Comment: Well, with an SPI bus at 8000hHz, that's unsustainable. Think 7 bytes per sample and a slow chip select and you're looking at 100Hz max. Then you have to do math on 16 bit numbers with an ALU that only does 8-bit add/subtract on a CPU that's busy running a game.

Comment: Well, I live and learn. Interesting. Thank you. I had assumed because SPI is so common, and straightforward, that it would be 1MHz.  Apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 6.3.2 and 6.3.3 of the application note explains how to raise an interrupt when an axis exceeds a certain value. Combined with a high-pass interrupt to get rid of the gravity vector, allowed me to set a really low threshold that triggers at 64mg.

```
  call DelayFrame ; raise CS

  ld a, LIS3DH_REG_WHOAMI
  ld b, a
  call ReadRegister
  ld a, c
  ldh [hWhoAmI], a

  call DelayFrame ; raise CS

; based on application note section 6.3.2-3
  ld a, LIS3DH_REG_CTRL1
  ld b, a
  ld a, $77 ; CTRL1: enable all axes, 400HZ
  ld c, a
  call WriteRegister
  ld a, $0F ; CTRL2: high-pass filter on everything
  call SPITransfer
  ld a, $00 ; CTRL3: not used
  call SPITransfer
  ld a, $88 ; CTRL4: BDU, high resolution, 2g
  call SPITransfer
  ld a, $08 ; CTRL5: latch interrupt on INT1_SRC 
  call SPITransfer

  call DelayFrame ; raise CS

  ld a, LIS3DH_REG_INT1CFG
  ld b, a
  ld a, %00101010 ; int1 config: enable high int on all axes
  ld c, a
  call WriteRegister
  ld a, 0 ; src
  call SPITransfer
  ld a, 4 ; threshold
  call SPITransfer
  ld a, 0 ; minimum duration
  call SPITransfer
```